# Tunnel connection to Mysql without SSH access

Tags: mysql, ssh, portforwarding, tunnel

From my local machine, I have SSH access to server A.
Once on Server A, I connect to mysql on server B via port 3306 on server B.

```
mysql -h <B.hostname>  -P 3306 -u <username> -p
```

I do NOT have ssh access to server B, either from my local machine or from server A.

What I'd like to do is have access to mysql on server B from my local machine.  Every tunneling/port-forwarding link I've found assumes that I can ssh into server B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh's -L takes a local port, a remote hostname to connect *from* the ssh server you connect to, and the remote port. In this case, you'll run:

`ssh -L 3307:B.hostname:3306 A.hostname`

This will make ssh connect to A, and when you later connect to port 3307 using a local mysql client (`mysql -H localhost -P 3307 -u ...`), A's sshd will initiate a connection to B.hostname:3306 for you.

Comment: many thanks.  for some reason I had to use 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost in the second step, but it worked.

Comment: That might be for a few reasons. For example, localhost might resolve to both an IPv4 (127.0.0.1) and an IPv6 address (::1), ssh could listen on 127.0.0.1:3307 only and mysql might try to connect [::1]:3307 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to use remote port forwarding. Try this on your local host:

```
[auto]ssh -R 1111:127.0.0.1:2222 -f -N -4Cp1234 username@servername.net
```

So you get on your `localhost:2222` (local machine) everything you get on `localhost:1111` (when you logged in on servername.net), with traffic going by SSH on `servername.net:1234`.

If your "server A" could access "server B" somehow, and you could access "server A" via SSH, that could probably help you.